# Read file contents in j2me

Tags: java, file, sorting, java-me

I Have a file like shown below,

```
OrderNo   id          name        count   Format
1         AA1       sdflsdfsdfd     12      01
2         AB2       asdaewqrftr     13      02
3         AA3       aerefytrsu      12      01
```

I want to read this file and want to sort with orderNo. Please suggest me some way to read and sort.(in J2ME). Thanks...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Do you just want to sort it in memory?  Or do you want to output a sorted file?

Comment: First i need to sort and store in memory, in future i will retrieve one by one

Answer (score 1):

- Create an object representing this
- Read [the file line by line](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/J2ME/ReadDisplayFile.htm)  ('\n' new line )
- Sort them in memory and write them back.

**Note:**

- Be careful about memory