# J2ME Offline Dictionary Application

Tags: dictionary, java-me

I want to develop a j2me dictionary application. Can I use a text file to store dictionary words instead of using rms?

How can I retrieve words according to user's need?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a text file however I dont think that solution would scale well and would be slow to search. Best case scenario for a text file solution you would have it alphabetically sorted and then you would have to search for the word you're trying to look up. Sounds painfully slow. RMS sounds like the better solution

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a file yes. How to read the content of files in J2ME has been asked and answered before, please see:

- [Reading Content from File in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8473382/reading-content-from-file-in-j2me)
- [Read file contents in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069879/read-file-contents-in-j2me),
- [Reading text file in J2ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/739691/reading-text-file-in-j2me)
- [how to read/write text file in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5204373/how-to-read-write-text-file-in-j2me)

From a performance perspective you would probably be better off using the RMS system, opening and parsing the files every time you want a word would probably not be very efficient.

Using the files as the means of getting the information onto the device however seems reasonable (as opposed to downloading that data after the midlet has been installed).